# User agent changing during connection

Tags: post, networking, server, get, user-agent

User agent changes within the connection, specifically differing between POST and GET requests.

- Why is this the case and why would this be desired functionality?
- How is this possible?

I'm really curious as to exactly why this is happening.

This is related to some log events where the user agent 'IEXPORE' is detected as a malicious user agent.

Please note that I've obfuscated it a tad.

```
POST /Citrix/StoreWeb/Resources/GetLaunchStatus/reafasdgsfgewsdfvxgrhgqer24t2g42HTTP/1.1
 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 Csrf-Token: 092590F290A09259E
 X-Citrix-IsUsingHTTPS: No
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
 Referer: http://FOO.BAR.FOO/RR/AA/
 Accept-Language: en-GB
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; wbx 1.0.0)
 Host: FOO.BAR
 Content-Length: 63
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Cookie: CtxsDeviceId=WR_Iiy9IeygDn1K3ZONz; 
----content-------

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
 Pragma: no-cache
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Encoding: gzip
 Expires: -1
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 X-Citrix-Application: Receiver for Web
 Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 08:09:51 GMT
 Content-Length: 60
 ----content----


 GET /Citrix/StoreWeb/Resources/LaunchIca/RKGAGYIGDXZID7894OWHIDSHS09ZCHFOADH094WFASFD?CsrfToken=04598F09A797E907AB07&IsUsingHttps=No HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: IEXPLORE.EXE
 Host: FOO.BAR
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Cookie: CtxsDeviceId=WR_Iiy9IeygDn1K3ZONz; CsrfToken=08608695765F870A09B90; CtxsPluginAssistantState=Done; CtxsAuthId=71973EA908B098F; CtxsPasswordChangeAllowed=true; CtxsDesktopAutoLaunchDone=yes; SITESERVER=MyhyIHUHiiyg7898HiugUG79hGIGo*; _ga=GA1.7.170929662.19346432; ASP.NET_SessionId=tnshshfshjjst
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? This log is from your server, or it's you testing something from a software?

Comment: @IgorServulo the log is from somebody else's server and end user device, and for both there is not much information. The end user device seems to be querying the server but with varying user agents.

Comment: Well, if the same end user is querying the server with more than two user agents that might be a discovery scan trying not to get caught. Altough, if its just Firefox and IEXPLORE.exe I don't think it's really a problem. I found a plugin on firefox that open your current tab on internet explorer, that might be something.

Comment: @IgorServulo very interesting! I should note that the file requested from the server is a .pac file if that has any relevance.

Comment: From what I know a .pac file is a proxy configuration file which makes sense since the server is hosting a citrix application. Looks very common.